# jQuery UI Autocomplete with a JSON datasource generated from Rails - not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to set up an input tag with jquery autocomplete function, but it's doesn't work when Im referring to an external JSON data. It works perfectly, however, with local JSON-like array... Let me explain this in my code:

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost:3000/autocomplete_searches/index.json",
    minLength: 3
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>


<body>
 <div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

autocomplete_searches_controller.rb in my Rails app

```
class AutocompleteSearchesController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @tags = Tag.limit(30).name_like(params[:term])
  @tags_hash = []
  @tags.each do |tag|
   @tags_hash << {"label" => tag.label}
  end
  render :json => @tags_hash
 end

end
```

This JSON action alone works very well, for example:
http://localhost:3000/autocomplete_searches/index?term=psychiatric gives me:

```
[{"label":"Psychiatric Hospital"},{"label":"Psychiatric Nurse"},{"label":"Psychiatric Examination"}]
```

And I can see that my jQuery function is also working somehow, because when Im typing for example "italy" in my #birds input-box WEBrick gives me:

```
Started GET "/autocomplete_searches/index.json?term=italy" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-09-27 18:07:07 +0200
  Processing by AutocompleteSearchesController#index as JSON
  Parameteres: {"term"=>"italy"}
  bla bla bla SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (tags.name LIKE '%italy%') LIMIT 30
```

But I see no effects on the website. And as I said, autocomplete script is working perfectly when I put data in the same format straight in my html file. In this one Im not getting any problems:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: [{"label":"Psychiatric Hospital"},{"label":"Psychiatric Nurse"},{"label":"Psychiatric Examination"}],
    minLength: 3
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>


<body>
 <div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So where's the problem? Im new to JSON so maybe Im doing sth wrong.

Comment: Does it help if you change the source to a relative url? e.g. - /autocomplete_searches/index.json.

Answer (score 0):

Ee... I made a new action in Rails and put this html code as a view. It started to work. But why I couldnt get it working while it was a stand alone html file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark but are you running the jQuery Validator Plugin? I've been having a bit of trouble with that interfering with my AJAX actions in its latest version.